# Django server doesn't serve requests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, web-development-server

I've got a django server up and running. When I try to it any api in it, it gives error "Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/" on postman. I've tried to access a single api directly from browser by typing "localhost:9001/". I have a default health check api which should ideally run on this, but none of my apis are working on this.

Comment: Please share the relevant code. which endpoint you are trying to access and also share the full error traceback. Currently, it is unclear.

Comment: My code started working after restarting my system... I don't understand the issue but its working fine.